# Grid display images while distorting size as little as possible

Tags: html, css, blazor

I'd like to be able to display a collection of images in a grid format without distorting the width/height ratio too much. Similar to the style of a website like pinterest.

Right now I have an unordered list, with a foreach that generates list elements.

```
    <ul class="pizza-cards">

        @if (specials != null)
            {
        @foreach (var special in specials)
                {
        <li @onclick="@(() => OrderState.ShowConfigurePizzaDialog(special))" style="background-image: url('@special.ImageUrl')">
            <div class="pizza-info">
                <span class="title">@special.Name</span>
                @special.Description
                <span class="price">@special.GetFormattedBasePrice()</span>
            </div>
        </li>
                }
            }
    </ul>
```

The issue with this is that all of the elements are sized in the same way. Which means that images that aren't square are distorted.

[image]

**The Goal**

The goal would be to be able to upload images (with additional information if needed) that could be dynamically displayed in a scrollable grid format like above, but without distorting the images too much. 
Something more like this: where containers adapt to better their children.

[image]

I've thought about doing this by letting the user pick a 'frame style' when uploading their data. And then wrapping each of those display styles inside of switch statement to decide how it would be displayed. But even then I'm not sure how you would avoid having the grid end up like below, where other list items are offset, and don't fit into all available space.

[image]

At this point I'm unsure which direction to move to do this right. And I'm hoping that someone with superior experience can help to point me in the right direction.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to replicate CSS Flexbox in CSS Grid. definitely look into Flexbox as it is capable of doing exactly what you are describing, and in fact, was designed for it.